# Default qualifier/filter for Spring Data Rest with JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to create a default filter in Spring Data Rest with JPA. I have a `Reward` class, and the Reward can have an exclusive relationship.

Here is a shortened version of the Reward class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Reward implements Identifiable<UUID> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Owner exclusiveOwner;
}
```

The `Owner` class has a `@ManyToOne` relationship to `Reward`.

I'd like to have it setup so that when `/api/rewards` is called it only returns Rewards who's exclusive relationship is null (i.e., generally available rewards), and when `/api/rewards?exclusiveOnwer=<UUID>` it only returns the rewards exclusive to that Owner.

I've gotten the second part to work with QueryDSL by having the `RewardRepository` extend `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Reward>`, but I can't figure out how to get the default qualifier to work. Is there any way to do that?

**Update**

I have tried a workaround by creating a handler method with QueryDSL Predicates based on the [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling). It is in my `RewardsController` class, which is a `@RepositoryRestController`. The method signature is

```
@GetMapping(path = "/rewards")
public ResponseEntity<?> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Reward.class) Predicate predicate, final FindParams findParams, final Pageable p, final PersistentEntityResourceAssembler entityAssembler) {
```

but that gives me the error
`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate]: Specified class is an interface` whenever I hit the endpoint. (`FindParams` is a simple POJO for capturing parameters. The same error occurs if I use a Map.)

There is [a bug with a workaround](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-838), but that requires changing the Controller from a `@RepositoryRestController` to a `@RestController`, which I don't want to do as 1) my API has a base path of `/api`, and 2) I already have a method in there that I don't want to break. If I change the Controller to `@BasePathAwareController` the problem persists.